# Regex for taking class name from string

Tags: c++, boost-regex

I have string like this one:

```
    parser = new ASTParser(in, encoding);
```

After i tokenize those string I get:

```
    ASTParser(in, encoding);
```

Now, how can I perform regex to get only ASTParser?

I tried to do this using `std::erase`:

```
    str.erase(std::remove_if(str.begin(), str.end(), isLetter), str.end());
```

but the problem is that I get also parameters (`ASTParserinencoding`) and I don't want this.

Also, I would very appreciate solution with `boost::regex`.

Comment: You don't need a regex for this, you can simply stop at the (

Comment: this is also a solution, but there can be more situations like: `ASTParser (in, encoding)`, `ASTParser;`. So, it is OK if I just stop if I find space, semi-colon, etc. or is some better generic solution for this?

Comment: I don't know how to use boost::regex, but if you have `ASTParser(in, encoding);` in a string, the regex `([^\(]+)` should be able to capture it, by capturing everything from the first character until `(` is seen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need for a regex -- all you have to do is scan until the first non-letter. Here's one way (note my std::string manipulation skills are a little rusty):

```
str.substr(0, std::distance(str.begin(), std::find_if_not(str.begin(), str.end(), isLetter));
```

Alternatively, you could use a regex like this:

```
([A-Za-z_][A-Za-z0-9_]*)
```